# Scala List[Unit] to List[String] conversion

Tags: scala, anorm

This is a pretty basic issue but I couldn't find a solution after spending an hour on it. I'm trying to query database to get a list of values through Scala Anorm ORM. I want to convert the result to a List[String] in order to pass to a Scala view.

But It shows a compile time error

```
 type mismatch;
 found   : List[Unit]
 required: List[String]
```

This is the helper function that interacts with the Db

```
def getActiveConceptNames(organizationId : Long) : List[String] = {
DB.withConnection { implicit c =>
  val conceptCountQuery = SQL("select * from tbl_concepts where org_id = {org_id} and is_deleted = 0;")
    .on("org_id" -> organizationId)
  conceptCountQuery().map { conceptRecord =>
    val conceptName = conceptRecord[String]("concept_name").toString
  }.toList
}
```

}

And I call the helper function in the controller like this

```
  val conceptNamesList = ConceptHelper.getActiveConceptNames(organizationId)
```

Comment: conceptCountQuery().map { conceptRecord =>
    conceptRecord[String]("concept_name").toString
  }.toList
?

Comment: isn't it possible to convert the returned record to string list that way ?

Comment: also asked at https://www.reddit.com/r/scala/comments/wxfi7z/scala_listunit_to_liststring_conversion/

Comment: That's a misusage of Anorm, rather `SQL"select concept_name from tbl_concepts where org_id = $organizationId and is_deleted = 0".as(scalar[String].*)` ([documentation](https://playframework.github.io/anorm/))

Answer (score 2):

When you use the `val` you define a variable which is not returned (thus the `Unit`).
Since there is a `[String]` I think the `.toString` part is no really needed.
And I don't think (though I could be wrong) that you should "call" `conceptCountQuery()` before the map, just the variable.
In addition, in a *very fast* skimming I did, it appears that
you need to use `as` and a "parser" to get from the query to the actual results.

Try

```
conceptCountQuery.map { conceptRecord =>
  conceptRecord[String]("concept_name")
}.as(scalar.List[String])
```

instead of

```
conceptCountQuery().map { conceptRecord =>
   val conceptName = conceptRecord[String]("concept_name")
}.toList
```

Comment: But this causes an error 
     diverging implicit expansion for type anorm.Column[T]
starting with value columnToString in object Column

Comment: I do not have any experience with ANorm. I have suggested 4 changes.

 1. Use `conceptQuery` without the parentheses.
 2. Do not assign to `val`
 3. Do not use `toString`.
 4. Use `.as(scalar.List[String])` to get the result.


Use them one at a time and see if the errors can tell you anything to guide you.